# Electron: how to make the Edit menu automatically enable/disable based on context

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, menu, electron

I'm working on a ReactJS Electron application which has an `Edit` menu (as all apps do). To make it a well behaved app from a UI/UX-perspective, I want the `Undo`/`Redo` entries to automatically "go grey" when there is nothing in the buffer, and of course, become clickable when appropriate. Same for the editing entries (`Cut`, `Copy`, `Paste`, and `Select All`).

However, the clincher is that these entries should only become active when the user has brought into keyboard focus an input control, like in a form. If the focus is not on the input control (or all input controls are hidden), then the `Edit` menu's entries should all be grayed out.

Presently, it seems that just plopping down an `Edit` menu in the top bar does not automatically exhibit this sort of behavior.

Is there a built in way of doing this in Electron, or does one have to "hand do it" for each possible control that can appear? In other words, do I have to add an event to each control on each form?